# Typescript How to initialize mixed type array with class-transformer

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, class-transformer

I have class with a property member of type array, an item in the array can be of several types for example MetaViewDatalinked or  MetaViewContainer, see example below

```
class MetaViewContainer{
      children: (MetaViewDatalinked | MetaViewContainer)[];
}

class MetaViewDatalinked{
     id: string;
}
```

I want to use class-transformer (`plainToClass(MetaViewContainer, json)`) to initialize the class with its properties.

if I had class without array see below, I would use @Type

```
class MetaViewContainer{
          @Type((typeHelpOptions: TypeHelpOptions) => {
               if (typeHelpOptions.object.container)
                   return MetaViewContainer;
               return MetaViewDatalinked;
           })
          child: MetaViewDatalinked | MetaViewContainer;
    }
```

The issue is `@Type` is called only once regardless of the property's type: a class or an array of classes, thus creating an array (in case of property being array) of single type.

Any ideas how to solve the issue are really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue with using `@Transform` decorator

```
class MetaViewContainer{
            @Transform((params: TransformFnParams) => {
                 const children: (MetaViewDatalinked | MetaViewContainer)[] = [];
                 if (!params.value) return children;
                 if (Array.isArray(params.value)) {
                    for (const item of params.value) {
                        if (item.children)
                          children.push(plainToClass(MetaViewContainer, item));
                        else
                          children.push(plainToClass(MetaViewDatalinked, item));
                     }
                  }        
                  return children;
          })
          children: (MetaViewDatalinked | MetaViewContainer)[];
    }
```